# What's the difference between executing python code via a task and "Run Python file in Terminal"?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am just getting my feet wet with Python in VScode.  I'd like to know what the difference is between using an extension like the [Code Runner Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) *(or creating a custom task)* to execute Python code and just right-clicking the Python file in the editor pane and selecting, **"*Run Python file in Terminal*** or ***Run current file in Python Interactive Window***?  What are the pros and cons between the two methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### its about performance hit

creating a **custom task** or **Run Python file in Terminal**
is equal to running `python my_code.py` in a terminal, and has almost no performance hit

any interactive and second layer for running python has some performance hits, e.g.
**Run current file in Python Interactive Window** or **using an extension like the Code Runner Extension**

*but don't forget the good things that come along with interactive running and extensions that make these performance hits bearable*

Answer (score 0):

The actions you see when right-clicking your file are an implementation of a [VSCode extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) that you have installed (Python base extension). What ultimately differs depends on the implementation of the specific extension (which you can check only by looking at their implementation) but I think that the main difference is in where your code is getting executed for you, which may be a new interactive window, an integrated terminal or vscode output window.

Answer (score 0):

Run Python file in Terminal simply opens up terminal in vsc in which the python script runs.
The interactive terminal has a ton of fuctions im to afraid of too explain but i have found this neat documentation about that.
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support#_python-interactive-window